# ManyToMany: what is the correct or best way to go in JPA?

Tags: java, mysql, jpa

I’m new to JPA and studying. When I have Many-to-Many relationship b/w tables in SQL for example Author and Book: I used a join table AuthorBook with composite primary key.

How should do it in JPA: Should I make only two entities Author and Book and create relationship ManyToMany with mappingBy one of them (in Author for example) and make another own owner of relationship: in Books (with using joinColumns).

Or should I also make a "join" 3rd entity AuthorsBooks with JPA? 
What way is correct? Are there actually different ways or an only way a preferable way?

Besides my specific question, I wonder if somebody know a good example/tutorial on this question? (I couldn't find a good one) Thanks!

Comment: "*Is there somewhere a good example/tutorial for this question?*" - [Questions asking us to recommend or find a book, tool, software library, **tutorial or other off-site resource** are off-topic for Stack Overflow as they tend to attract opinionated answers and spam. Instead, describe the problem and what has been done so far to solve it.](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic)

Comment: I would go with the `@ManyToMany`-annotation, specifying the `JoinTable`, `JoinColumn` and `ReverseJoinColumn`. Creating a Join-entity feels wrong and artificial.

Comment: Thank you, I found two options but guessed the option as you suggesting is correct and are asking here, because good to know expert opinion to be sure.

Comment: Please take everything with a grain of salt. My knowledge on JPA and Hibernate is self-taugth as well. The way I see it is as follows: specifying the relation through the annotation is (mostly) readable and centralized. Introduching a new, artificial, object introduces additional complexity w.r.t. readability. It might be that creating this artifical object somehow boosts performance (I neither have evidence for nor against it), but as long as there is no problem, do not try to fix it.

Comment: Think domain-first, and then find ways to persist your models. Does an an `Author` make sense in the problem domain? Probably. `Book`? Yup. `AuthorsBooks`? Not so much. The whole idea of JPA is that you shouldn't have to introduce artificial constructs to your domain model just because you want to persist it.

Comment: Yes, that sounds reasonable. If I have a MySQL database with Author, Book and AuthorsBook, and only two tables will in JPA with ManyToMany relations: so when I create Author and Books and relations between them in JPA then will JPA (or supposed to) persist it to AuthorsBook in MySQL database, right?

Comment: I'm not entirely sure what you mean by 'two tables in JPA'.  `Book` and `Author` are entities (domain objects),  not tables. And yes, JPA will find a way to persist the many-to-many association between them (by resorting to the creation of an intermediary table). My point was,  you shouldn't concern yourself too much with how exactly JPA does its job, the burden is on JPA to work it out. Just focus on designing the domain model so that it fits your application well.

Comment: Thanks, I'm trying now to test it.

Answer (score 0):

I found different sources with solution. the best in my opinion is like here: think is here https://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/Java_Persistence/ManyToMany
They say it's a standard way to make two entities with manyToMany association, however if the join table supposed to have additional columns is a best way to make three entities including an entity for join table (examples are given in the link for both situations)